# PowerShell: How do I set an Environment variable as the directory represented by another env. variable

Tags: powershell

The title is probably not clear enough since I'm not too sure I'm using the correct jargon; Which could very well be the reason for not finding any solutions to this issue yet.

I've been able to use powershell to append a directory to Path by using:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";%DOMINO_HOME%", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

However, how can I set the directory represented by Domino Home?

For instance, in a batch file, **%DOMINO_HOME%** would literally add it's directory - E:\Lotus\Domino and **%%DOMINO_HOME%%** would add %DOMINO_HOME%.

I want to be able to add the directory (E:\Lotus\Domino) using PowerShell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy enough, all of your environment variables are stored in a `$env:` variable. Which actually makes your entire task much easier...

```
$env:Path += ";$env:DOMINO_HOME"
```

That should append your %DOMINO_HOME% to the end of your path. (worked for me and my environment variable VS90COMNTOOLS)

Comment: Jeez, that was simple!! `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", $env:Path + ";$env:DOMINO_HOME", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)  ` worked perfectly well. Thank you.